# Is it possible to get a wide camera shot without warping?

Tags: animation, workflow

This may just be impossible but I am wondering if it is possible to get a wide angle shot without strange perspective and warping of the image, or is there a way to adjust the way a wide shot warps?  I am just learning about the camera and perhaps there is a setting/technique that I do not know about?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very wide shots are always bound to get some distortion around the edges, however if you don't decrease the focal length too much it should be acceptable, after all we are talking about a virtual camera, there are no actual lenses to distort your image.

Otherwise, I don't know if this fits your needs, but you could try a panoramic camera in Cycles. Just select the camera then go to the Properties Window > Object Data (Camera) > Lens and click *Panoramic*.
You can only get a preview through the viewport *Rendered View* or by rendering out an image.

Comment: Blender perspective camera has no distortion what so ever (other than 3 point perspective) - so no distortion around edges. This is the perfect camera with perfect perspective. To get warped perspective you need the Panoramic type (like you say in 2nd paragraph).

Answer (score 4):

In both the physical world and the computer modeled sense, yes.

While it is vastly more complex to achieve it with a physical camera, it is possible with precise optics. The term typically is referred to as *rectilinear distortion* when it is unintended. Unintended because some lens optics are designed to deliver a spherical image such as fisheyes, while others deliver cylindrically compressed imagery such as anamorphic.

In the case of your question, it is unclear whether you are referring to physical optics, which may suffer from rectilinear distortion, or computer generated work, which will only have perspectival distortion typically.

In the simplest of senses, the field of view is a byproduct of lens length with gate size.

So while it is tricky judging your desire from your question, you can achieve your goal from within Blender by adjusting your field of view and your gate / sensor dimensions.

Remember, optics are optics and a wider lens with a smaller gate size will exacerbate the perspectival vantage. Longer lenses will compress the perspectival components. To disable the perspectival aspect, you could also consider an orthographic camera.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the gate/sensor dimensions and the field of view?  Is "field of view" the same thing as "focal length"?

Comment: No, FoV is a byproduct of gate size and focal length. Focal length determines the qualia of the light and perspectival qualities, while the gate dimensions determine how much of that projection is captured. See http://www.panavision.com/sites/default/files/docs/documentLibrary/2%2520Sensor%2520Size%2520FOV%2520(3).pdf